# 2 similar views and templates but only one template shows form options

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm really stuck on this one.  I have a working view/template that has a form select option that populates options from my model

```
views.py

def random(request):
    classroom = Classroom.objects.filter(teacher=request.user).order_by('course_block')
    classblock = request.GET.get('class_block')
    students = Student.objects.all().filter(classroom__course_block=classblock)
    nicknames = [s.nickname for s in students]
    data = serializers.serialize("json", students, fields = ("nickname", "attend"))
    student_names = json.dumps(list(nicknames))
    context = {'students': students}
    context['classroom'] = classroom
    context['student_names'] = student_names
    context['data'] = data
    template = loader.get_template('randomizer/randomize.html')
    print (data)
    return render(request, 'randomizer/randomize.html', context)

ramdomize template

{% extends 'randomizer/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
   <div id="djangorandom">
   {{ classroom.id }}
      <form action="{% url 'randomizer:random' %}" method="get">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control" name="class_block">
                   {% for room in classroom %}
                       <option value={{ room.course_block }}>{{ room.get_course_block_display }}</option>
                   {% endfor %}
               </select>
            </div>
           <span><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
       </form>
   </div>


Page source returns:

<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="class_block">

            <option value=11>Block 1-1</option>

            <option value=13>Block 1-3</option>

            <option value=14>Block 1-4</option>

            <option value=P13>Pair 1-3</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

Now I've copied a lot of this code for a slightly different template and purpose:

```
def pair(request):
    classroom = Classroom.objects.filter(teacher=request.user).order_by('course_block')
    classblock = request.GET.get('class_block')
    students = Student.objects.all().filter(classroom__course_block=classblock)
    nicknames = [s.nickname for s in students]
    data = serializers.serialize("json", students, fields = ("nickname", "attend"))
    student_names = json.dumps(list(nicknames))
    context= {'classroom': classroom}
    context['students'] = students
    context['student_names'] = student_names
    context['data'] = data
    template = loader.get_template('randomizer/pairing.html')
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'randomizer/pairing.html')


{% extends 'randomizer/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="djangorandom">
    {{ classroom.id }}
        <form action="{% url 'randomizer:pair' %}" method="get">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="class_block">
              {% for room in classroom %}
                <option value={{ room.course_block }}>{{ room.get_course_block_display }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <span><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

But the page source doesn't show any of the options for the form selects:

```
<form action="/randomizer/pairing/" method="get">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ADVUsnTserljrnDvRlmeTPyvjMOzva5xj7t8LSeDmPxnkBUtx4XmfXAI5aRfJky6' />
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="class_block">

        </select>
    </div>
    <span><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
</form>
```

I've practically copied everything from the first view/template to the second view/template.  I wondered if there was a scope issue where `def pair` re-uses the code from `def random`, but I commented out `def random` and that didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure your Django templates are in `app/templates` directory (if `app` or any other name is in `INSTALLED_APPS`) ?  Whatever is not in templates dir within app, will be checked in your root `templates` - also check your `TEMPLATES`: `OPTIONS`: `loaders` in `settings.py` for having `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` and others. Then you don't have so specify the directory - just make sure the html template is in one of the searched `templates` locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second view doesn't pass the context into the `render()` call, so there is no `classroom` variable and nothing to iterate over in the template.

(Note, in both views the `template = loader.get_template(...)` call is irrelevant and not used; you should remove those lines.)